# Submit form with dynamic created selectbox

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I'm trying to submit a form on a page with multiple forms. The form need to submit a value from a select/dropdown box. This selectbox is dynamically populated. Everything works but it seems that the script doesn't submit the first option. I need to change the selectbox and then it works. When I don't change the selectbox nothing is submitted.

I tried to make the first option selected but that doesn't work either.

Any one knows what I am doing wrong?

POPULATE SELECT BOXES

```
     <script type="text/javascript">  
       $(document).ready(function(){            
        $.getJSON('product.html?format=json', function(data){              
         $.each(data.product.variants, function (index, variant) {
           $('#product_123').append(new Option('' + variant.title + ' (€'+ variant.price.price +')', '' + variant.id + ''));
            });                
           }); 
         }); 
      </script>
```

HTML

```
    <select id="product_123"></select>

     <a href="#" class="actionbutton prodorderbtn submit">Order</a>
 </form>
```

SUBMIT

```
 <script>     
     $("#product_123").change(function(){
      var pvid = $('option:selected', $(this)).val();

      $(".submit").on("click", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#formProduct123").attr("action", "/cart/add/" + pvid).submit();
        return false;
       });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: Are there multiple forms and products? Each with `form#formProduct<id>` and `select#product_<id>`? Or are there multiple forms for the same product? Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: @user41047: Yes indeed multiple products and each product has the code above in it. So each product has a form and submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the submit bit:

```
 <script>     
     $("#product_123").change(function(){
      var pvid = $('option:selected', $(this)).val();

      // on click handler is set every time the option changes
      $(".submit").on("click", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#formProduct123").attr("action", "/cart/add/" + pvid).submit();
        return false;
       });
     });
  </script>
```

Notice how the click handler is nested in the `change`. This means no click handler is registered *until* a change is made.

I propose the following solution: Simply check what the value is whenever the user submits, rather than update the handler.

```
  var product = $('#product_123');
  var form = $('#formProduct123');

  // Set the handler once at the start, and check the value at the time of submit.
  $('.submit').on('click', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pvid = $('option:selected', product).val();
    form.attr('action', '/cart/add/' + pvid).submit();
    return false;
  });
```

## Generalizing to multiple forms

We will still set the `onclick` handler once at the start. During a click we look for the parent form, and the sibling option. Please verify that this DOM traversal works for you.

```
$('.submit').on('click', function(){
  e.preventDefault();
  var submit = $(this);
  var form = submit.parents('form').first();
  var selected = form.find('option:selected');
  var pvid = selected.val();
  form.attr('action', '/cart/add/' + pvid).submit();
  return false;
});
```

I strongly advice you to drop the `onchange`. Consider the following:

1. User select some option for product `A`.
2. User decides to buy product `B` instead, and presses submit for this product.

   1. Product `A` was the last to change, so product `A` gets submitted instead.

Comment: This seems to submit only the last form on the page. Like mentioned I have multiple forms on a page.

Comment: Ok this works. I understand what you mean with the on change stuff. Pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You use use event delegation to set the following up such that you do not have to run the code when the select content is added to the DOM:

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on('change',"#product_123", function(){
        var pvid = this.value;
        var form = this.form;
        $(form).attr('action', '/cart/add/' + pvid);
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

Also after you append the select, run the following code:

```
$('#product_123').change();
```

That should do it. In effect your combined code becomes:

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on('change','#product_123', function(){
        var pvid = this.value;
        var form = this.form;
        $(form).attr('action', '/cart/add/' + pvid);
        form.submit();
    });

    $.getJSON('product.html?format=json', function(data){              
        $.each(data.product.variants, function (index, variant) {
            $('#product_123').append(new Option('' + variant.title + ' (€'+ variant.price.price +')', '' + variant.id + ''));
        });
        $('#product_123').change();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't submit the first option.

Comment: K. Will update my code shortly. I think I now know what's going on.